# Regex - I need to include non-alphabetic character

Tags: c#, regex

i have this expression and i need to make sure to include at least one non-alphabetic character

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)\S{8,12}$
```

- testhis invalid
- testhis7 valid
- testhis@ valid

Comment: `testhis` invalid because it only has 7 non repeated chars and you demand 8. The regex given already matches the other 2?

Comment: Is this to validate a password is strong enough?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a positive lookahead asserting at least 1 char other than a-zA-Z

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*[^\sa-zA-Z])\S{8,12}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*(.)\1)` Assert not 2 consecutive chars
- `(?=.*[^\sa-zA-Z])` Assert 1 char other than a whitespace char and a-zA-Z
- `\S{8,12}` Match 8-12 non whitespace chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%28.%29%5c1%29%28%3f%3d.*%5b%5e%5csa-zA-Z%5d%29%5cS%7b8%2c12%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=testhis%0d%0atesthis7%0d%0atesthis%40%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0atestthis7%0d%0atesthis7test%0d%0atesthis%40test%0d%0atesthis77%0d%0atesthis%40rr&o=m)

Another option is to use `\P{L}` to assert any char other than any kind of letter from any language

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*\P{L})\S{8,12}$
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%28.%29%5c1%29%28%3f%3d.*%5cP%7bL%7d%29%5cS%7b8%2c12%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=testhis%e0%a4%b6%e0%a5%82%e0%a4%a8%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%af%0d%0atesthis%40%0d%0atesth%e4%ba%94is%0d%0a%0d%0atestthis%e6%9c%88%0d%0atestthis7%0d%0atesthis7test%0d%0atesthis%40test%0d%0atesthis77%0d%0atesthis%40rr%0d%0a&o=m)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do it with separate if-statements. This way you'll have exact information what is missing in the value. With regexps you'll only get a true/false result if the value matched the pattern or not - you'll have no information WHAT is missing in the value.

For example:

```
if(!value.Any(c => !char.IsLetter(c)){
    throw new Exception("value must contain at least one non-letter")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for the special character (as matched by `[\p{P}\p{S}]`) in positive lookahead `(?=.*[\p{P}\p{S}])`, which gives you the regex:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)(?=.*[\p{P}\p{S}])\S{8,12}$
```

[See online demo](https://regex101.com/r/5f4xhN/4)

You can also replace `[\p{P}\p{S}]` by `[!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_‘{|}~]`, or any other character set that list all the characters that you want to count as being "special characters".

Comment: .NET regex does not support POSIX character classes.

Comment: No, OP says there must be at least one non-letter char. `\p{P}` only matches punctuation proper, but does not match symbols. Also, `\p{P}` is [not equal](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cp%7bP%7d&i=%5cp%7bP%7d+by+%5b!%22%5c%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2b%2c%5c-.%2f%3a%3b%3c%3d%3e%3f%40%5c%5b%5c%5c%5c%5d%5e_%e2%80%98%7b%7c%7d%7e%5d) to `[!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_‘{|}~]`

Comment: Sure, I can see that `\p{P}` is substantially different than POSIX `[:punct:]`. Do you know any better way to replace `[:punct:]`, than using the character set, like the one at the and of my answer?

Comment: `[:punct:]` is similar to `[\p{P}\p{S}]`

Comment: Yep, I changed it to `[\p{P}\p{S}]` as this seems to work really well. Thanks again for sharing your expertise :)